# I need a button click instead of setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this code but for my site I need a button instad of setInterval. I tried `jquery("#btn").click(function(){})` but can't get it working.

```
<script>

jQuery().ready(function(){
  setInterval("getResult()",1000); //set theinterval for the update
});

function getResult(){   
  jQuery.post("update.php", function(data) {
    jQuery("#readings").html(data);
  });
}
</script>
<div id="readings"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your function like this:

```
<button onclick="getResult()" >Get result</button>
```

Comment: That works. How can I post variables in this script like name = {NAME} and request = {REQUEST}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `click` event listener to a button. The jsfiddle below should help you. This can be done using pure `JavaScript` but as you suggested jQuery.

```
<button id="test">Test</button>

$("#test").click(function() {
   alert("Click event!"); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/89987ps1/